# .net framework 4 in windows 8.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a project which needs to be debugged in Visual Studio 2010 with .net framework 4

Since I'm using Windows 8.1, I found that .net framework 4.5 is installed with o/s

I tried to install .net framework 4 using web installer and standalone installer from Microsoft site. It gives an error stating that because of higher version it cannot be installed.

Can anyone suggest a workaround on this.

Thank you.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 includes .NET 4.0. If you have 4.5 you have 4.0 aswell (or... it's backwards compatible, whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change de .net Framework to use in the project properties (Right clic on the Project --> Properties --> Application).

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround for this case. You will have to find a Windows Vista or Windows 7 machine, as .NET Framework 4.0 can only be applied there. Windows 8 and above like you discovered always ships with .NET 4.5 and above.